# Why does my text get compressed when I include the view in Main

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

When I add my elements to the Main view they look good. But when I put them in another view and include that view in the main view, they look compressed.

[image]

When I paste the HomeView code into the Main view it looks fine:

[image]

Main view code that causes text to be compressed:

```
Ext.define('DeclarationApp.view.Main',
{
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    requires:
    [
        'DeclarationApp.view.HomeView'
    ],

    xtype: 'main',

    config:
    {
        layout: 'fit',
        styleHtmlContent: true,

        items:
        [{
            xtype: 'homeview'
        }]
    }
});
```

Both views are Container, changing the view type does not help.
I've tried adding flex: 1 and scrollable: true, does not help.

Why does this happen? Or how can I find out in Sencha why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

The attribute styleHtmlContent: true was on the child attribute, apparently this caused stuff to get compressed.

Even though layout: 'fit' is necessary, otherwise nothing will show.

But even then the menu bar is still compressed :(